# Is it possible to have a "pure" feudal society?

Tags: magic, government, feudalism

Edit : Pardon my ignorance because I may very well be misconstruing terms that I have very limited understanding of.

I read somewhere on this sub that pure feudalism is just a contract-law approach to government. While the king/lord theoretically owned and ruled over the entirety of the land, most of it was rented and parceled out to vassals and common folk. There were apparently explicit and implicit feudal agreements/ contracts between lords, vassals and common folk, as long as the obligations were upheld every class had more or less freedom to do as they like. On the downside failure to uphold obligations or one's end of the feudal contract would result in either slavery, serfdom or death.

Basically I read (to my utmost surprise) that feudalism was actually quite democratic on the local level. While on the higher level the common people did not have a say in who got to be leader or what policies got enacted, the common people could choose their own leadership and if the town or village paid it's taxes and fulfilled it's obligations properly the lords and vassals didn't meddle in their internal affairs.

Could such a contract based society prosper/endure let alone exist be it in the past, present or future?

Comment: You'll be fine so long as your lord respects your right to life and liberty. Cos if he doesn't, the period between now and his next tax period could be somewhere between unpleasant and fatal. Luckily, human leaders have never had a history of stupidity, senility, psychopathy or a tendency to hallucinate, so everything will be great, forever!

Comment: (also, whilst I like the fact that your hypothetical reasonable government has been tagged `magic`, it isn't strictly necessary as the question doesn't mention magic at all)

Comment: @starfishprime Yeah I see that I was being a little naive. I guess you're right human leaders are very prone to making irrationnal morally and ethically questionable decisions.

Comment: are the feudalism has something similar like magna carta in it ?

Comment: Just a quick little quibble; serfdom really shouldn't be compared with slavery or death.  In many jurisdictions, serfdom wasn't all that bad.  Obviously being poor sucked, but it was actually often better to be a poor serf than a poor freeman.  Serfs were protected by their lords and his men-at-arms, free people had no such protection, and the medieval world could be pretty violent.

Comment: @LiJun Yes definitely the Magna Carta is actually where I got the inspiration from which is why I am asking

Comment: @Ryan_L Thanks a lot for clearing that up !

Comment: *"Pure feudalism is just a contract-law approach to government:"* that's an interesting description of a society where the vast majority of people could neither read nor write... Not to mention that by definition contract law needs an independent judiciary, which was utterly absent in most (or may all, in cannot think of a counter-example) for-real feudal societies.

Comment: @AlexP While you're correct about horrible living conditions, from what I understand the person was using "contract" figuratively. For example your lord vowed to protect you and rent you a place to live,  in exchange you would pay him taxes or in food, failure on either part of the "contract=agreement" would have dire consequences for both parties. Either way doesn't really matter since my setting is fantasy so I quite like the magically binding contract angle and might look it how to succesfully implement the concept.

Comment: Many more or less pure or impure, more or less feudal societies have existed among Humans on Earth for decades, or centuries, or possibly even millennia, before eventually changing into other forms of societies.  Thus it seems that more or less pure or impure, more or less feudal societies can be approximately as well working and stable as example of other types of societies.  Of course it is historically disputed where pure feudalism ever existed, or even if there were any feudal societies.  Continued.

Comment: Examples of societies whose laws and customs were created by nobles from feudal Europe trying to design societies that would be perfect (from their point of view, of course) include crusader sates like the Kingdom of Jerusalem and the Empire of Romania (better known as the Latin Empire of Constantinople).  Possibly the opinions of historians on how purely feudal they were and how well they functioned as a result would be useful.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Thanks for your insight ! I'm definitely going to ask historians for more help on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, this is a very interesting question! I wonder if you were thinking of any feudal system in particular when you decided to ask this. I'm guessing you meant the Western kind.

The short answer would be: I don't think so.

The long answer would be: while such a society could exist in the short-term, I fear it would not be able to endure organically. Human nature makes it impossible. You would need people with no ambition, people with no drive to have more or do more, people who are content with their lot in life. In other words, people who don't think. While you could argue that there is such a thing as [sheeple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheeple), you can't expect all people to be complacent with their situation.

Of course, you might be able to do so if the contracts used were magical and forced all parties to uphold it lest they face some unpleasant consequences, sort of like an [Unbreakable Vow](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/unbreakable-vow). That would take care of both all the [Gollums](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Gollum) and all the [Morgoths](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Morgoth) of the world. It would also be a society ruled by immediate [karmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) causality and purity as related to [civic duty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civic_engagement) and [role ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_ethics). I believe [Fundamental fairness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_justice) and a sense of community would be very important indeed in such a feudal system.

Depending on how inflexible and indifferent the contracts were would determine how long it would take before the [negativity bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias) became too great and the feudal system built around the contracts also collapsed. Assuming, of course, that there was no clause in the first-ever contract saying that all the fiefs, lords, princes, kings, and people with people under their care or service must ensure all their vasals or wards are bound by contract to conserve their freedoms within previously-stipulated and acceptable societal parameters.

It would be a very oppressive system, though it could be argued that it would be for the sake of World Peace if done right. Ends and means, you know how it goes. But if done wrong—well. Let's not think about that.

Comment: Definitely a great help ! Considering this is for a fantasy story I don't mind if it collapses/changes it would actually add to my story. Also You're right, completely forgot to factor Human nature into the mix. So I guess I'm going to have figure out some kind of magically binding contract that would also be flexible enough for writing interesting plots  (political machinations,rebellions,wars...etc).